# Making a Dart Widget to Zoom and Scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

I made this code to allow Scrolling and Zooming because there is a conflict between those two.

```
class ImageScrollViewNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  ScrollPhysics pagePhysics = const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
  void updatePhysics(ScrollPhysics physics) {
    pagePhysics = physics;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
class Zoom extends StatefulWidget {
  final TransformationController transformationController;
  final List imageList;
  final Size screenSize;
  final int index;
  const Zoom({super.key, required this.transformationController, required this.imageList, required this.screenSize, required this.index});

  @override
  State<Zoom> createState() => _ZoomState();
}
class _ZoomState extends State<Zoom> {
  late PageController imagePageController;
  late TransformationController transformationController;
  late List imageList;
  late Size screenSize;
  late int index;

  @override
  void initState() {
    transformationController = widget.transformationController;
    imageList = widget.imageList;
    screenSize = widget.screenSize;
    index = widget.index;
    imagePageController = PageController(initialPage: index);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ImageScrollViewNotifier>(builder: (context, value, child) {
      print(value.pagePhysics);
      return PageView(physics: value.pagePhysics, controller: imagePageController, children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++)
          SafeArea(
            bottom: false,
            child: Stack(children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: screenSize.width,
                child: InteractiveViewer(
                  onInteractionStart: (details) {
                    details.pointerCount == 1 && transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis() == 1
                        ? value.updatePhysics(const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics())
                        : value.updatePhysics(const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics());
                  },
                  onInteractionUpdate: (details) {
                    details.pointerCount == 1 && transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis() == 1
                        ? value.updatePhysics(const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics())
                        : value.updatePhysics(const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics());
                  },
                  onInteractionEnd: (details) {
                    value.updatePhysics(const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics());
                  },
                  transformationController: transformationController,
                  minScale: 0.4,
                  maxScale: 4,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Image.file(
                      imageList[i],
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          )
      ]);
    });
  }
}
```

In  this code I can see the value  of pagePhysics updating when the conditions is meet, can see the change between AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics and NeverScrollableScrollPhysics on the console, but it seems to not slide between the PageViews, maybe the Widget is not rebuilt on Consumer, which I doubt? I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: Solved with a modificiation of this:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68594